# Is this mysql statement inefficient?

Tags: php, mysql

Quite simply, is such a query/statement inefficient or bad?

```
<?

 $strSql="SELECT * FROM clients, projects
           WHERE clients.clientID = $intClientId
           AND projects.clientID=$intClientId LIMIT 1";       

  $objResult=mysql_query($strSql);
  if(mysql_num_rows($objResult)==0) { 
      echo("No data"); }
  while ($arrRow=mysql_fetch_array($objResult))
  {
    ?>
    <h1>Sub Project(s) for: <span><?=$arrRow[clientName]?></span></h1>
    <?
  } ?>
```

Comment: ISTR there's a codereview site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should avoid using `SELECT *` and select only the fields you need unless absolutely necessary. Whether or not this is efficient depends on how your tables are indexed. I assume in this case that that `clientID` is the primary key of the `clients` table. If you have an index on `clientID` in the `projects` table, this query should be quite fast.

Comment: so $strSql="SELECT clientID,clientName FROM clients WHERE clients.clientID = $intClientId"; - this works, and alot more efficient? :)

Comment: If all you need is the `clientID` and `clientName`, then yes. But it seems you want information on projects as well.

Comment: To expand on Michael Mior's answer, if all the columns you want are indexed, it may be possible to return the results without ever actually going to the table itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that are off here:

- As Michael Mior mentions, you should avoid `SELECT *`. This can be an efficiency issue. It can also break applications in some cases if your application makes assumptions about the columns that are in the table and then the table changes in the database.
- You have a `LIMIT 1` in your query, but then you loop over the results. This doesn't make sense because `LIMIT 1` means you'll only get one row of results, regardless of how many rows matched your query.
- You are not escaping your inputs. This may be OK in this case if, in earlier code, you have already verified that those variables definitely contain integer values. I generally just use prepared statements and avoid this problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

And i also want to add one little advice: Try not to use php shorttags(Use `<?php echo` instead of `<?=`) from now. Since PHP6 it will not be supported and it might create code errors and other difficulties for you in the future.

Comment: I don't agree. Short-tags will be fully supported but not enabled per default.

Comment: If server belongs to yourself, of course you can do with php.ini what you want. But there are million starter developers which have website on shared hosting and aren't able to change any setting.

Answer (score 0):

When writing, or should I say developing new features, one should always debug and run a performance profile on query to ensure that you'r using proper index(s). Always use EXPLAIN (or EXPLAIN EXTENDED if your into specifics) on a query to determine its performance.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM clients, projects WHERE clients.clientID = 1 AND projects.clientID = 1
```

I noted also that your doing a while() loop, which is unnecessary if your are only fetching a single row.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer writing `projects.clientID=clients.clientID` so to be more easy to see how the tables are joined.

The other thing I will avoid (mostly for clarity) is the `while` loop. Since you expect one record, no need to loop over the result set.

And finally, it is not a good idea to use the short tags.

Comment: If there isn't a `UNIQUE`/`PRIMARY` index on `clientID`, `LIMIT 1` will save MySQL some work.

Comment: Even without `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` index on `clientID` probably there are no more than 1 client with the same id

Comment: Sure, but MySQL doesn't know that if there isn't an index without doing a full table scan. `LIMIT 1` will truncate the scan when the first (and only, but MySQL may not know that) one is found.

Comment: MySQL's query planner is intelligent enough to know that if you've told it to `LIMIT N` and there's no `ORDER BY` clause that it doesn't need to finish the table scan once it has collected `N` rows. You can demonstrate this by running `EXPLAIN`, or you can find the proof in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html **"If you are selecting only a few rows with LIMIT, MySQL uses indexes in some cases when normally it would prefer to do a full table scan."**

Comment: Uau. I didn't know this. Glad I participated in this discussion. Thanks for pointing it out. I will delete the statement from the answer so not to confuse someone.